# CakePHP - can't create more than one method (admin_index) in plugin

Tags: cakephp

I'm a newbie in CakePHP, please have patience with me :)

So, I'm trying to create a plugin called References. I've baked "plugin's core" through cake's console. Then I've created ReferencesController class that extends ReferencesAppController and Reference class (model) that extends ReferencesAppModel. My next step was creating action admin_index (just code to save form), it's view and a little bit validation in Reference model. To my problem, I'm unable to create any other action, ex. admin_add. When I do (I create new action and I add it's view), then I try to access it through the URL (localhost/my_project/admin/references/add), and there comes the message "Error: References.AddController could not be found.". I am not sure, what I do wrong, I don't want to create another controller, just action. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because only the plugin index action (when plugin and controller have the same name) is directly routed.
For all others you need to verbosly add the plugin name and the controller name to the url:

```
/my_project/admin/references/references/add
```

If you had created a link to this action, the routing would have shown you that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck there for a day. THANKS !